# Communicating between forms

Tags: winforms, dictionary, c++-cli

I have a main form from which I generate multiple subforms. I store these forms in a `List<Subform^> ^` variable so that I can send messages to them from the main form. I load new forms like this (from memory, might not compile):

```
Subform ^sf = gcnew Subform(some, variables, here);
subforms->Add(sf);
subforms[subforms.Count-1]->Show();
```

My goal is to remove the subform from the list once it's closed. I've been considering moving to a dictionary for simpler form identification, like this:

```
++i;    // Some sort of a form counter. to access them when closing.
Subform ^sf = gcnew Subform(some, variables, here);
subforms->Add(i, sf);
subforms[i]->Show();
```

How would I remove the ith form when closing? Perhaps something like this (in pseudocode)

```
sf->FormClosed = subforms->RemoveAt[i]; // Before I add it to the dictionary.
```

?

Comment: You can still use a list instead of a dictionary. But you will have to iterate through the list to find the form you want to remove.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
sf->FormClosed += gcnew FormClosedEventHandler(this, &RemoveSubform);

void RemoveSubform(System::Object^ sender, FormClosedEventArgs^ e)
{
    subforms->Remove(sender);
}
```